# Restricting folder names by (regex) pattern

Tags: hippocms

I would like to restrict my folder names based on a pattern. Eg, I want folder names to be years. Is this currently possible in hippo 7.8.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using the folderWorkFlowplugin, this is unfortunately not (very well) documented, but you could take a look at https://issues.onehippo.com/browse/CMS7-6652